# plot multiple Y values against a single X values

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have four lists with data:

**[RED_LIST], [GRE_LIST], [REG_LIST], [NIR_LIST]**

Each list has data like this ...

```
 1.6044503709230613,
 1.6044503709230613,
 1.6044503709230613,
 1.6044503709230613,
 1.6044503709230613,
 1.6044503709230613,
 1.6044503709230613,
 1.6044503709230613,
 1.6044503709230613,
 1.6044503709230613,
 1.6044503709230613,
```

I have already plotted each one as Y values against X :

[image]

I want now to plot the four lists in one figure against the same X values.

How can I do it?

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**:

```
# Create a list of 4 X vales
X =[[X1],[X2],[X3],[X4]]
# Create one list of Y valeus containing the foue lists
Y = [[RED_LIST],[GRE_LIST],[REG_LIST],[NIR_LIST]]
    
plt.figure()
plt.plot(X,Y),plt.title("Bande Passante vs Reflectance Capteur:"),plt.xlabel("Bande Passante"),plt.ylabel("log1/Reflectance")
```

**EDIT & SOLUTION**

So the question was solved by @Paul H and here is the solution:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for Y in [RED_LIST , GRE_LIST , REG_LIST , NIR_LIST]:
    ax.plot(X, Y)
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the 4 lines to appear on one subplot of a figure? Or do you want 4 separate subplots to appear in one figure?

Comment: @DavidG 4 lines to appear in one subplot of a figure

Comment: Could you provide an example of XXXX and YYYY?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for Y in [YY_RED, YY_REG, YY_NIR, YY_GRE]:
    ax.plot(X, Y)
```